# how to change inside tag with grid layout in css

Tags: html, css

my code is for grid layout:

```css
.tc-row{
    display:grid;
}
.tc-cell1{
    order:2;
}
.tc-cell2{
    order:1;
}
input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tc-row">
    <div class="tc-cell1">
        <input type="number" name="quantity" value="100" class="tm-qty tm-bsbb" size="4">
    </div>
    <div class="tc-cell2">
        <input type="text" name="text" class="tm-bsbb" size="4">
        <span class="tc-price-wrap">Total Price: $79</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to display total price after quantity filed.

update: the total price was showing in bottom of all filed.

1. text field.
2. quantity field.
3. total price text.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like this. You just have to reverse the order of `tc-cell1` `tc-cell2`.  See this:

```css
.tc-row{
    display:grid;
}
.tc-cell1{
    order:1;
}
.tc-cell2{
    order:2;
}
input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tc-row">
    <div class="tc-cell1">
        <input type="text" name="text" class="tm-bsbb" size="4">
    </div>
    <div class="tc-cell2">
         <input type="number" name="quantity" value="100" class="tm-qty tm-bsbb" size="4">
        <span class="tc-price-wrap">Total Price: $79</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: Editing after OP modified the question

Comment: i can not move the input. i want to order with css just.

Comment: @yasintaqizade how to you think the order will work if the grouping is in  any order? You may consider putting all `total price` in a separate order.

Comment: You can put `text` , `quantity`, `total price` in order 1, order 2 and order 3 respectively